# Pinout for a 6 pin 3x4 keypad

Tags: pinout, keypad

I have this old keypad sitting around, never used it because I could never figure out the pinout for it. Anyone know how this would be wired to something such as a picaxe/arduino?

Front of the keypad, with the plastic buttons and case removed:
[image: Front, plastic removed]

Back of the keypad, same conditions as first:
[image: Back, plastic removed]

Front of the keypad, with the buttons on:
[image: Front, buttons on]

Edit:
Forgot to say, the keypad was pulled from a fried 12v door lock.

This one, if anyone is interested: http://www.jaycar.com.au/Access-Control-%26-Automation/Access-Control/Keypads-%26-Standalone-Controllers/Self-Contained-Security-Keypad/p/LA5355

Answer (score 2):

Figuring out the pinout of a simple matrix keypad is pretty simple: identify (number) the connector pins, then make a table of which connector pins become shorted as each key is pressed.

Your 6-pin connector has 1- square pad at one end with the remaining pads being round.  The normal convention is that the odd pin out is #1 so let's call that square pad pin #1.

Now simply follow each key's traces to the connector pads and make your table.

For example:

(1) is pins 1, 2

(2) is pins 2, 6

(3) is pins 2, 5

Etc.

It looks as if this is a fairly non-standard matrix in that the rows / columns have 5 keys each instead of 3 & 4.  This allows the designer to get away with using only 6 pins on the connector instead of 7 pins.

That's okay - the principles or reading the keypad remain the same: set one row active (the remaining rows non-active), then see which of the columns also became active.